# Add an item for each list value

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to add a value for each item in a list and have problem

```
m = ['ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c'] //in this example i will make the value a list

only_guid = ['d25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626', 'e0f7cc56-ef22-495f-8a3c-02680430cec0']

//if I make the value "m" a list, then the code below will help me, but this is not the result that I expect

t_only_guid = []
for i1 in only_guid:
    t_only_guid.append([[i1,i2] for i2 in m])

print(t_only_guid)

//result
[[['d25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626', 'ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c']], [['d25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626', 'ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c']]]
```

How to add for each list item if "m" just a value?

```
m = 'ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c'
```

I expect the following result:

```
[['d25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626', 'ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c'], ['d25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626', 'ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c']]
```

I hope for your help with an explanation.
Tnk you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isinstance` to test the object and process. Also you can use `itertools.product` here.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import product

t_only_guid = ['d25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626', 'e0f7cc56-ef22-495f-8a3c-02680430cec0']
m = 'ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c'
m = m if isinstance(m, list) else [m]   # works if m is a list -->['ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c']
print(list(product(m, t_only_guid)))
```

**Output:**

```
[('ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c', 'd25170b0-87c8-4d40-80b7-05829d6d8626'), ('ad3f788a-4cb0-4981-9510-bc5f5758622c', 'e0f7cc56-ef22-495f-8a3c-02680430cec0')]
```

Comment: WOW. You are very fast! Thank you for help! Your option works!

Answer (score 1):

just change your code like this.

```
item = '1'
lis = ['1','2']
new = []
for n in lis:
    new.append([n,item])
print(new)
```

Result :

```
[['1', '1'], ['2', '1']]
```